# Converting sqlite3_column_blob to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, blob

I have been trying to add `sqlite3_column_blob` type of value to `NSString` by this lines of code :

```
NSUInteger len = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, n);
NSData *cData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, n) length:len];
NSString *columnText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cData bytes]];
```

Here is the BLOB data which i am trying to retrieve from the database :

```
�PNG


IHDRXXq�04sBIT|d�
�IDATx��{pEǿ�   !�f��E���0��#����Q'p@iQ��È�L�P���R`6    F�COJD�q��0 ��\�FbrȁR�������c6��������f�����M��-����n"�~;�p0s��bɶX,c�U^7!�Q!��e�n�2��o�%��#���~3G!�^�X,��<�b��B\S�)ˬ`��Ť*S��#�.�9+c�8ADtN�fd�}����D4��̊�X����u9��f�y̜/_�c�
"J�D�V0�^"�0��h6��Du��,3s83���f"z��j���6M]!V�[q���\��+��O�QUU�K�.*~:���@HH�|�]�F�@tt�'�C�$wU�+<ט��  >}���`��rR�b<�sv��\��'Nb�8~�$��F��h����<z$��1�U{�J�t@'9��~e��X|*�b�I��]��+�:|F��B��6$IB��~xd��>aa����$�/�j��f�H��
rV����ز{>��ju1�Q��'�E�+}Q�/^��&����r�۰Ǿ>����A�:g�S��(��r}Q�Of���
��t��omƶw5Y7�-�$aꔉH�5]��>KD�}1�J`f0@7!DM`7u=p�0Vg��ҥ_��&%,�2^L�#Æ��ʘ�CI�*�8HD���-03�oko��7n"7�mߥ�ѷ���'b��9v:r='���z�������V^ͅ_���E�%z����bU�rt���|"z����y���ݴ��+0��y+.�`��P^^ᬈ�ow�n����S�� %5���[O�t�W������3yB�:]3s["�L;u��g4z�O��uH[�� 2=.�=ƣ>��;x��gA1+/�@JjZ�W����u&DG�����l%�jw�p)03��h�:���/�����^���"<�nl|#O����[$I��jdᮋ��%�7����ŋ���4�eܸq�!O�f���ݙ+;h%��o�z�зOO�I�1����`��g��*�yȫg���pd�x�v]__�=��Ǟ��4?^�()-Gn�,yA�(���wo��A���G��D��Sv&&No'.,9�����J����/�ۥL�0��L����s�m߅ke�4ڻ��.j6�aUV�ΦݢW�D�V!$$D3?$$��L�̞�j6���6H�=��L�u�Vy-r֚��z�7u�K۱K�����u6z���Ꙉ��?�Jpp̚��{�M����Xn�hŸ��x�71k�Sn�8!!!����M����
oۥ�5R�9�`�NB��D4˚VRZ��3��m����<���Ǿ>�s�.�����g@d���о���A��ᴨ�����t������
$I���ۙ:��-I�^$"������<�����_X�G��jL���Vy%ns��C�$!絕��+D�X�Zm�E0sof���E�%-N\���/ߴ
=t�w�h��(�3odf;+���Tc���j@���������Sv�n�]hb����nVRUU�lx�I��x��3=�@�Fc(Lٙ���=��[�N��-
m�  ,O��V$?��غ'�#oͪ�׊���5�<Y�O?s0
�WO��i�l���
p|\l��k�*r|\�G����v�j�Ǐ���l~
ߝ�5~q[Q|\,^�{-�ŵb4�����<����nBD�d�6������h��9���J��b�o
�7W����8���b�}�y�,03G1s!T.���O�|�U�����h~``4�"�侻(<~R�4���9
�B,`�T__���2�n���.k��Zi߾V������攨 R���E8�7~8W�r�p��M,{e�W�[?�Ѭ� fs�~�ë����R�l�����L���$i=T�_+�6��K0w�R]bm�`rr�y\�W���%��\���zd����$IkY`"�ff�9�?���!zD޶}�m�JN�:�l�z��b����:�(B����.x0<�RT\���]��m�.d����MEV�Z�"��uX�(]׊�Z+I����_�n�TQS����>ۙ��w~��Z��Y��;?qH���ù"]����fذ�"�9SY��o�{�h��}�'X��OP��:+�Ndo��b�L�^=Iv=}@��еk�|�l(E�Wq����Ů�v7J\@S�pf~���3?�̛�%���ѫʬ<y?��+Z���Q�����:�3�i���zB�/҈h���̊7�J���   �Z/�    �:'�������)�u"z����Z����rЪ���$��։F%e(K�� �XSӾ��=��2�����`;��=�w7}�Z�Zٴ� ,��sb�׉}+�t����Z��u�AD)�B�{�[q�Z+"J�ƫ�ڃ����V9��
��
!�~�":�Kx�k��'8��3����`I�V�ۛk0�{S�G���Z�q���6{p%8�,�4�o�42���i>IDC��P�"����FC1���^ڊ���(/ˈh�rs�ڳ���[�{$&�kW���t�a��2��DtEY��+FDq��?�m�U�%��F����c���06ƍMnM8a�X��Q��6��������}�1��־X�����>�ѭ�(j�5m�3�;l���q��s�J"���R��9��C�|��@f�Z.Uf"J%"���@D�(���U��I�����&��9��Ҙ�]"�!���BD5AAAO3�m�=6&�&��*~G1i�x���AAAO����f��$I�)����4�X�$,��̴KSk��ݿy;g����a�"�A�Z<K���&u2ҝ���Q����u6-�<����p�,�����V���s�E�kQ��Dc�¹β55��I@�MD�:���)��ZD�W��uB��5�6f�*I�W9<
)`3?�c�R�RfK�Cʨaf�����盓���8åx ���L���,%�    N�k�@D�̼[�ֿ_�Yݢ<��֬v0�3�n���tO�$Ir�ڷOO�7��1rXX'�7�o��yZ����}5���Dc�y=���78�v�o�����c���������A��}�Up�b"����A�a~�(!D=���_��\\���a�m��:��%�&̼S��b��]�f#3��Jd��
6���<u�D�I���^&�����b\94L�/�j� �E�%شy���d�a�1}�����$�����ڋ8p�0�-l�c�I���ô�L���c�A%����tE1���wv�m>�d�|P�5T-��~{P�3,�j�X-�����QY�3��+PU]�˗�@JJ�����DC��бct��@��(DFޏ޽=Z�b悠���:j�r��R��aQ1Ζy|I��b�~o/)���g�h�R�!r��XN'���C\����DtV��M>����Z�9�G����L!D�Ƒ�
�%S.��GN�
�CSW4����vhj�v�!P���?�  �kɲIEND�B`�
```

But every time i am getting nil response although there is a value exist. Rest of the parameter values are coming just i am getting nil response in above value.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the character encoding of the blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for the above issue which i was facing :

```
NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 2)];
NSString *columnText =  [content base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot convert that data to a string is because it's a PNG image file:

> �PNG

(I assume; I haven't looked at the PNG spec to confirm this, it's just an assumption at this stage).

Comment: so do i need to remove that part from the database ?

Comment: @Mayur That's a funny question.  I think you need to sit down and think about this for a minute.

Comment: may be :) but i really not getting please provide me any reference so i can get it.

Comment: @Mayur OK, what you think is a column containing a string, is not and instead it contains an image.  Can you tell me what the column is called please, as it's conventional to use meaningful names, and it might add more insight.  It could just be a bug in whatever is writing to the database; but I have no way of knowing that from here.